# struts2 jaspers shows FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, struts2, jasper-reports, jasper-plugin

I am trying to integrate jasper with struts2 by using the following [tutorials](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/jasperreports-tutorial.html).

But the jasper compiler not able to acess the file and my code is given below

```
ServletContext context=ServletActionContext.getServletContext();

URL is = context.getResource("/jasper/our_jasper_template.jrxml");  
String path=is.getPath();
String jasper = is.getPath().replace("our_jasper_template.jrxml", "our_compiled_template.jasper");
System.out.println(path); //here displays the path
JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(path,jasper); // here throws FileNotFoundException
```

If I change the `path="C:\our_jasper_template.jrxml"`(keeping file there),
compiler reads file, but fails to save file to `our_compiled_template.jasper`

(shows `Error saving file: jaspers\jasper\our_compiled_template.jrxml`)

I went through many suggestions ,  but I failed to correct it . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getRealPath()` is the answer.

So i changed above code as below and got output

```
ServletContext context=ServletActionContext.getServletContext();

String path= context.getRealPath("/jasper/our_jasper_template.jrxml");
```