# How to get use getRealPath in Strut 2

Tags: jakarta-ee

I have a `xml` file named `Students.xml` in web folder.

Link: `../web/Students.xml`

I was try get that file by using the below code:

```
String path = ServletActionContext.getServletContext().*getRealPath*("Students.xml");
```

but it doesn't work.
Any suggestion. Thanks

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782928/struts2-jaspers-shows-filenotfoundexception

Comment: ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getRealPath("/Students.xml");
I forgot this one "/" lol.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you want the path of the file in Struts2. Try getting it from the session like this.

```
session.getServletContext().getRealPath("/Students.xml");
```

This Shuold work..